# Could not open or put a Hibernate Session in ValueStack: Cannot open connection

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, struts2

I have created application using struts and hibernate. While running application am getting following error in Eclipse IDE:

```
org.hibernate.SessionException: Error! Please, check your JDBC/JDNI Configurations and Database Server avaliability. 

 Could not open or put a Hibernate Session in ValueStack: Cannot open connection
    com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.intercept(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:134)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
```

Any clue?

Regards,

Comment: Any clues to overcome this Error?

Comment: org.hibernate.SessionException: Error! Please, check your JDBC/JDNI Configurations and Database Server avaliability. 
Cannot open connection

Comment: Is this a customized error message?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a dependency of asm and cglib in my pom.xml .Did you added that?Please check it once.

[see here](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-hibernate-integration-with-full-hibernate-plugin/)  for example

Comment: @user2189411 did you check my answer

Comment: Thanks fr your answer PSR. am using simple Dynamic project in Eclipse Indigo. am not using Maven project to add POM.xml file.. In this case how can i solve my issue?

Comment: @user2189411 No problem.you can download those jarfiles manually then add to build path

Comment: I have added following jar files and done build path also      antlr-2.7.6
commons-beanutils
commons-collections
commons-fileupload
commons-io
commons-lang
commons-logging
displaytag
displaytag-export-poi
dom4j
ejb3-persistence
freemarker
hibernate3
hibernate-annotations
hibernate-commons-annotations
hibernate-validator
hsqldb
itext
iText
javassist
jcl104-over-slf4j
jstl
jta
junit
log4j
mail
mysql-connector-java
ognl-2.7.3
poi-3.2-FINAL
slf4j-api
slf4jlog4j
standard
struts2-convention-plugin
struts2-core
struts-dojo-plugin
struts-fullhibernatecore-plugin
xwork did i miss any jar files?

Comment: No am getting same error after i added jar files in above comments. did i missed any jar files?

Comment: I think you missed some jar files.

Comment: Could u able to say which JAR files i missed?